# QTP Installer code for windows application

Tags: vbscript, qtp, windows

I am working on QTP automation systems. I need to write custom code in order to pick an Installer for my application and run the same. Can any one help me to guide with code snippet that I should write in order that:

1. The code should be able to pick the installer from a folder path
   location and run the latest Build Exe installer. The exe files are
   kept on a folder path sorted as per date.
2. Also, the code should be able to move the installer to click to
   next--> next selection and finally finish during the complete
   installation process.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part you can use `filesystemobject` to find all files in the folder and you can execute the latest file by using `SystemUtil.Run "path to the latest file"`

Check the link http://www.qtpworld.com/index.php?cid=41 for more details on how to use File System Object.

For the second part you have to run the installer from QTP and record all actions that you need to perform on the installer. This will work only if all the installers are having the same user interface or the same set of buttons.